# ember js find records by multiple ids

Tags: ember.js

in Ember data we have:

```
this.store.findQuery('book', 1);
```

will return in **/books/1**

Now I want to return a list of id such as **/books/1,2,3,4**

What can i do? I also try

```
this.store.findQuery('book','1,2,3,4');
```

But there are 2 problems with this: 
 1. it return books/1%2C2%2C3%2C4 : comma is decode to html char, so not working 
 2. as far as i know findQuery is only used to find single record with ids, not by multiple record
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/finding-records/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to find all records with a given ID. For this there is a query object which you can pass filter

```
this.store.query('book', {reload:true, filter: {book_ids: '1,2,3,4'} })
```

This will hit the server /books?filter[book_ids]=1,2,3,4 and then on your server side you can find all records that are inside this array 1,2,3,4 , like SELECT  * BOOKS WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4) - not sure what you use on server side.

reloed: true is optional - this is if you want to force reloading data every time you visit route. This is explained here in section querying for multiple records

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/finding-records/#toc_querying-for-multiple-records